# Django migrations on gitlab CI/CD creates the same 0001_initial.py every time

Tags: python, django, yaml, gitlab-ci

I've configured GitLab CI/CD for my project.

Suppose that I have a model named News and I want to add a new field named `'yyy'` to it:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="News Title")
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description")
    yyy = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # New field
```

And my .gitlab-ci.yml file is like this:

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - source /path-to-my-project/venv/bin/activate
    - cd /path-to-my-project/
    - python3 manage.py makemigrations news
    - python3 manage.py migrate news
```

Every time I add a new field to any table and push the changes, `gitlab-ci` creates the same `0001_initial.py` file and I see this message on `GitLab CI/CD console`:

[image]

This causes some `inconsistent` errors ( for example when I want to add a foreign-key field to the model ).

> A change that I did on GitLab CI configuration was that I
>
> changed `Git strategy` on the `General pipelines` section from
>
> `git fetch` to `git clone` and set the `Git shallow clone` to 0.
>
> Settings -> CI/CD -> General pipelines

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Why is your build step making migrations at all? you should be committing them.

Comment: @Sayse sounds right. I think this is where the error occurs. Where should I put the migrations in .gitlab-ci.yml ? I'm new to Gitlab CI

Comment: making migrations has nothing to do with CI

Comment: @Sayse So you say I have to go to the server and make migrations and then restart the server manually? and I can't handle this in CI?

Comment: I'm saying make the migrations when you're developing and commit them to your source control